# Content Encoding Error

Tags: firefox

I just upgraded to Firefox and it is now giving me this error on certain webpages:

```
Content Encoding Error

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.
```

I'm using Firefox 29.

I'm visiting this page:
http://www.quora.com/Is-the-force-necessary-to-leave-Earths-atmosphere-constant

Comment: Do you get the same issue in [Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)?

Comment: Well, it works now??? I cleared my cookies, restarted the browser and tested it again and it was failing. I browsed Quora and other pages were working. Now, going to that page it started working!? If it happens again I will try it in safe mode see if I can reproduce the issue.